# ¿Cualquier página o sitio web que contenga interacción puede denominarse aplicación web?

Tags: javascript, html, aplicación-web

Tengo la duda sobre el alcance del término aplicación web. 
Si me baso en la definición de Wikipedia:

> se denomina aplicación web a aquellas herramientas que los usuarios pueden utilizar accediendo a un servidor web a través de Internet o de una intranet mediante un navegador...

¿Algo sencillo como lo siguiente sería correcto llamarlo aplicación web?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<button onclick="myFunction()">como te llamás?</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var persona = prompt("escribe tu nombre");
    if (persona != null) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "hola " + persona + "!";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Según las definiciones algo así podría llamarse sitio web, página web o aplicación web.

¿Es así? ¿Es indiferente o lo correcto sería llamarlo de una determinada manera?

Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si. No solo es correcto sino que pueden existir páginas que funcionen sin ningún tipo de javascript, por ejemplo sitios gubernamentales y militares.

La clave esta en la palabra

> [...] a aquellas herramientas [...]

También si vas a la correspondiente en [inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application) verás que dice la palabra clave

> [..] aplicación cliente-servidor en el cual el cliente es un navegador

Y a su vez en [aplicación de software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software)

> Una aplicación de software es un programa de computadora diseñado para ejecutar un conjunto de funciones tareas o actividades para el beneficio de usuario.

Así que básicamente la función o tarea de tu programa es **saludar** usando una tecnología cliente-servidor y es visualizada con un navegador por lo que puede considerarse una aplicación web.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Entonces podemos decir que cualquier página o sitio web que se muestre en un navegador es una aplicación web, independiente de su contenido, por mas que sea un simple hola mundo..?

Comment: @agujex El propósito del *hola mundo* es enseñarte a programar. Siempre que sirva a algún proposito y lo cumpla usando la arquitectura señalada, no importa quien se beneficie puede ser considerada una aplicación web. Ten presente que las aplicaciones móviles o híbridas también pueden considerarse *técnicamente* aplicaciones web ya que los `web-view` son básicamente un navegador inscrustado dentro de una ventana.

Comment: Gracias @devconcept, ya lo tengo claro. Pasó que quedé confundido investigando sobre el tema ya que en sitios que visité diferencian una página web de una aplicación web, y esto no se correspondía con la definición. Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Cualquier aplicación que es almacenada en un servidor remoto, se distribuye en el internet y es accedida  a través de un explorador Web.

Answer (score 0):

Según diferentes desarrolladores, la diferencia básica entre una aplicación web y un sitio web es la interacción que se presenta con el usuario, siendo la de la aplicación mucho más compleja.

Ejemplos de aplicaciones web pueden ser google maps, google docs,etc. Ejemplos de páginas web pueden ser blogs personales o wikis.

Puedes leer un artículo sobre tu pregunta en el siguiente link:
http://www.visionmobile.com/blog/2013/07/web-sites-vs-web-apps-what-the-experts-think/

Comment: Gracias. Justamente por definiciones cómo esta surgió mi duda, pero si vamos a la definición, todo sería una aplicación web... o cuál sería el límite que divide una cosa de la otra?